# Clean way to split an array into thirds and display to user

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a sorted array in a perl script eg:

```
qw(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll)
```

Is there an easy way to display it in three columns so that

1. first third is in left column
2. middle third is in middle column
3. and last third is in right column

This is so the elements can be displayed running down the screen instead of across it. eg

```
aaa eee iii
bbb fff jjj
ccc ggg kkk
ddd hhh lll
```

I have been trying to use modulus but it's getting complicated and thought there might be an elegant solution. Ultimately I intend to use it for something similar to `select` in bash.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( part );
my $num_rows = int(@a/3);
my @aoa = map [ @a[@$_] ], part { $_ % $num_rows } 0..$#a;
print("@$_\n") for @aoa;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( part );
my $num_rows = int(@a/3);
my @aoa = part { $_ % $num_rows } 0..$#a;
print("@a[ @$_ ]\n") for @aoa;
```

or

```
my $num_rows = int(@a/3);
for my $row_num (0..$num_rows-1) {
   print("@a[ map { $row_num + $num_rows*$_ } 0..2 ]\n");
}
```

---

Versions of the above that don't assumes @a % 3 == 0.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( part );
use POSIX           qw( ceil );
my $num_rows = ceil(@a/3);
my @aoa = map [ @a[@$_] ], part { $_ % $num_rows } 0..$#a;
print("@$_\n") for @aoa;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( part );
use POSIX           qw( ceil );
my $num_rows = ceil(@a/3);
my @aoa = part { $_ % $num_rows } 0..$#a;
print("@a[ @$_ ]\n") for @aoa;
```

or

```
use POSIX qw( ceil );
my $num_rows = ceil(@a/3);
for my $row_num (0..$num_rows-1) {
   print("@a[ grep { $_ < @a } map { $row_num + $num_rows*$_ } 0..2 ]\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks ikegami, I like your last solution, for others using `ceil(@/3)` triggers a "Possible unintended interpolation" if you're using `use strict`

Comment: @David, That message comes from warnings, not strict, and my code does not produce it. You changed something (incorrectly) if you got that.

Comment: not complaining, anyway I've gone back to play with it again, and can't recreate the error I saw, so no idea how I managed to do it! :)

Comment: voted as correct answer as your last use got me the closest to what I needed. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4):

After reading this question, it looked a lot like an [example](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aForm#Layout-control) that I read in the docs for [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aForm). ( Which is the Perl5 implementation )

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Perl6::Form;

my @array = qw'aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll';

print form
  "{[[[[[:} {:[[[[:} {:[[[[[}",
  \@array,  \@array, \@array;
```

```
aaa      eee      iii
bbb      fff      jjj
ccc      ggg      kkk
ddd      hhh      lll
```

It won't work like you want it to, if any of the strings is longer than has been allotted for it.

```
...
$array[-1] .= ' lllllll';
...
```

```
aaa      fff      kkk
bbb      ggg      lll
ccc      hhh      lllllll
ddd      iii
eee      jjj
```

Of course you could calculate the required width before the call to [form](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aForm).

```
...

use List::Util qw'max';

my $max_length = max 5, map length, @array; # at least 5
my $TERMINAL_WIDTH = 80;
my $number_of_cols = int( $TERMINAL_WIDTH / ($max_length+1) );

my $single = '{:' . ( '[' x ($max_length-4) ) . ':} ';

print $single, "\n\n"; # debug statement

print form
  $single x $number_of_cols,
  (\@array) x $number_of_cols;
```

```
{:[[[[[[[:}

aaa         ccc         eee         ggg         iii         kkk
bbb         ddd         fff         hhh         jjj         lll lllllll
                                                                            80 ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, hope it helps you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll");
my $size = @arr;

my $column = 3;

my $mod = $size / $column;

my $i = $size;
my $count = 0;
while ($i > 0) {
    my $k = $count;
    while ($k < $size) {
        print "$arr[$k]\t";
        $k += $mod;
    }
    print "\n";
    $count++;
    $i -= $column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks lightbringer, Here's some notes about your solution: Adding extra items to the array causes items to appear at the end of one column and the top of the next, adding longer items causes the columns to lose alignment

Answer (score 3):

```
my @foo = qw(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll);
my $rows = int( (@foo+2) / 3 );
my @row;
$row[$_ % $rows][$_ / $rows] = $foo[$_] for 0..$#foo;
for my $row (@row) {
    print join(' ', @$row), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thansk ysth, Here's some notes about this solution: Extra items are handled well by adding extra rows, columns don't line up if the items in the array aren't the same width.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = qw(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll);
my @aoa;
push @{ $aoa[ $_ % 4 ] }, $a[$_] for 0 .. $#a;
print "@{ $_ }\n" for @aoa;
```

Comment: Thanks Kenosis, Here's some notes about your solution: Extra array items are added as another column to the left, columns don't line up if the items in the array aren't the same width

Answer (score 0):

4 LOC: Very Simple...ENJOY

```
 my @tokens = qw(aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll);
 my $text = join(" ",@tokens);
 while($text =~ /[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+/g)
 {
     print "$&\n";
 }
```

Samir

Comment: Thanks Samir, Here's my notes about your solution. Works good for when divisible by three, but drops extras if it's not. Columns don't line up if the items in the array aren't the same width.